# Cannot see my sites in my internet domain

Tags: internet, dns

I made an account in 000webhost.com for freehosting. And I uploaded three files(html and php files) with compressed ".zip" form in public_html and I want to see my site what I did in my html and php file. I see on the link "www.mydomain.com".(mydomain means what I used in my account as my domain name). But I see HugeDomains.com and it shows that link "www.mydomain.com" is for sale. I don't know how to see my uploaded site.

Comment: you haven't bought a domain & you get a subdomain when you register for 000webhost.com. use mydomain.000webhost.com to visit your site. Also, unless you have uncompressed the zip file, you won't see anything either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have bought a domain (like `test.com`) you need to set `000webhost`'s `DNS` to your domain.

To point your domain to `000webhost`, you need to visit your domain registrar (where you registered the domain) and change the name servers associated with your domain to `000webhost` name servers and also remove any existing name servers that may be associated with your domain. It will start working in 1 to 48 hours.

---

But if you haven't buy a domain and you don't know the name of your free doamin, login to `000webhost` and you will see your domain name. Click on it and that's it.

[image]